# How to make objective-C function run serially with Core Data issue?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, sequence

I am writing an iOS program that downloads a JSON file from server then saves data to Core Data. After that the program reads that data from Core Data to decide which file to download next from server. 
However I figure out that it always do the reading part first then do the download part. I guess it is because of multi-thread issue. I have read how to do serial dispatch queues but these methods run in different view controller so I do not know what is the best way to solve this issue.
I would like to ask how to make them run serially?
Below is my code:

```
DataManager *dataManager = [DataManager sharedManager];
        if ([dataManager downloadSubjects] == TRUE) { // save JSON data here
            if ([dataManager downloadTopics] == TRUE) { //read JSON data then download next JSON file then save do Core Data
                if ([dataManager downloadQuestions] == TRUE) { // read from Core Data and download next JSON file and save to Core Data
                    NSLog(@"Downloaded everything");
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: We have very little to go on here. There is nothing _explicitly_ asynchronous or multi-threaded here. If you're right, the code in question is in the `DataManager` class (which which can't see). Does the DataManager have a delegate or do the methods have alternatives with completion handler blocks?

Comment: how are you downloading the data? chances are that you should put downloadTopics and downloadQuestions in completion handlers of the previous network operation